# Why an event cannot be dragged above 11:00 pm in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I post an event in Google Calendar, say for example from 12:00 am - 1:00 am. I tried to extent that particular event to the whole day till 11:30 pm, but I couldn't extend it more than 11:00 pm. Is there any specific reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

I do believe you've found a small bug related to how the drag extender works.

However, this may be as designed to prevent display weirdness from happening since events longer than 24 hours automatically go into the all-day event area of the calendar regardless of being marked as all-day.

Here's what I found:

1. Cannot drag extend an event past the midnight hour of the current day (regardless of start time)
2. If you start an event at midnight today initially created to last 1 hour, when you drag the event down you cannot go past 11pm
3. If you start an event at 1am today initially create to last 1 hour, when you drag the event down you cannot go past 0:00 next day
4. If you manually edit the event to go from 00:00 today to 23:59 today and then drag extend it, it pops back to 23:00 as the maximum end time for dragging.
5. If you manually create an event starting 00:00 to 23:00 and drag & drop the whole event past the midnight hour you cannot drag the event past the 23 hour long mark. Even though the event is spanning across days.

Extra Notes:

1. if you manually create an event to go from 00:00 today to 00:00 (or longer) tomorrow it ends up in the all-day events area of the calendar without having the all-day event flag. However, you cannot drag extend an event to be longer than the today's time without manually editing the event.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because, if you wanted a whole-day event, you can create this sort of thing by clicking in the zone just under the day's date.

Otherwise you can create your event, click it, select "edit event" and change the end time to whatever you like.